# Jquery Tracking checkbox changed from checked to unchecked or its already unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Suppose I have four check-boxes in a form Check-a,Check-b,Check-c,Check-d.

Check-a and Check-b are already selected.I can get which check-box is checked or not unchecked by using Jquery.

Now I have unchecked Check-a. So Check-a were checked and I had made this unchecked from checked. So now Check-c and Check-d were already unchecked and Check-a is unchecked by me.I am in search of a way to track which are unchecked from checked and which were previously unchecked.

Can Anyone Tell me a way ?

Comment: Just set a Boolean variable when the checkbox is `.change()`d.

Comment: can you please help me with a sample code.Will i have to maintain a boolean array for this ?

Comment: I can't help you with my sample code until I see yours. How you store the Boolean variables depends on what you want to do with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the same HTML as @definitelyundefinable, this does kind of the same thing but it's slightly cleaner because it doesn't use hidden fields, and fake arrays (as strings in the hidden field)

```
$(function() {
  var history = [];
  $("input").click(function() {
    history.push({
      id: this.id,
      checked: this.checked
    });
  });
  // If you'd like, you can initialize the array
  // with the initial values with the following line
  $("input").click();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need a kind of click-history, why not just use an extra field?

html:

```
<form>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="o" id="orange" />
        <label for="orange">orange</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="a" id="apple" />
        <label for="apple">apple</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="history" id="history" />
    </div>
</form>
```

jquery script:

```
$("input").click(function() {
    $("#history").val( $("#history").val() + $(this).val() + ";");
});
```

you can make it hidden and evaluate the ; separated list afterwards..

Comment: There's no need to make it a text field, use a real array

Comment: true, but if it has to be sent to the server anyway, Id guessed a string might be a simple solution